# Movie about World War I

Tags: identify-this-movie

There was a movie I watched a few years ago and seen it only once. It was about World War I:

- It was in colour
- I am fairly sure they were Australians going into the air force to fight the Germans, they trained in the UK.
- The movie was obviously in English.
- Despite saying the movie might have had Australians in it, I am not sure what country of origin the movie is from.

### This is what I remember from the movie:

- There was some young men who wanted to fight in the war for the allies, they chose to go to the airforce.
- When they got to the United Kingdom, they did extensive training.
- One training objective they ahd to complete was the following:

  1. One person has to sit in a chair (a spinning chair), they spin for about 10-20 seconds, only enough to get dizzy.
  2. When the person stops spinning (a bystanding person stops the chair) they have to walk and balance on a railway track and get to the other side (a single track)
  3. If they fail to do this, I am certain they have to do the spinning chair thing again before reattempt at walking the track.

I am certain this is training that if you are spinning in a plane (doing rolls) you must be able to keep your coordination at a high standard and keep fighting without wacky flying.

- The young men did this test multiple times and they quite enjoyed it. They did this indoors.
- The next training objective was the following:

  1. The trainees were to stand in a little cockpit with a machine gun with live rounds.
  2. The cockpit moved along a track slowly and the trainees, while moving have to try a shoot at multiple targets that are stationary. If they miss even 2, they have to start again.
- There were more training objectives, but I can't remember them.
- So after they finished their training, they learnt in-air sign language and practiced this.
- So when after this happened, they went to war after learning how to fly the planes.
- I think it was over Belguim where they first flew over, I'm not sure, but they flew in a formation. There were quite a few planes. There were people on the ground cheering.
- When They saw German planes, they each gave each other the sign language for 'up' (which is a thumb pointing up).
- They flew up and then they went into contact with the German planes. They had acquired the lookout German Blimp.
- They fought with extroardinary performance, a few of the allied planes were shot down, but a great many were the German planes.
- One guy was shot through the chest (allied) and decided he had to end the conflict, he smiled to either his assailant or a friend ( I can't remember), he flew up over the blimp (vertical) plane turned towards the ground and he flew straight into the blimp, causing it to blow up, the German troops on the blimp had to run for it.
- Another battle I know of is when there is a red baron, he had shot down many planes, he shot down quite a few allied planes and one of the main characters decided to shoot him down.
- So the man took off in a plane by himself later in the movie to go and kill the red baron and found the guy over a field. The allied plane started to dive toward the 'not-yet-in-the-air'-red baron.
- The red baron quickly took cover to avoid the bullets but after the attempted strafe he took flight quickly to combat the allied plane.
- The 1v1 battle took a while before two of the other allied planes (the guy's friends) arrived to also combat the red baron.
- When the allied guy lost his bullets, (the other guys were shaken off to fight off other planes) because they fell out of the gun, the red baron took aim directly behind him, the allied guy knew he was going to die and closed his eyes, put his head back and braced himself.
- The red baron then fired but didn't hit the allied man.
- The allied man then performed a monouvre (mind my spelling) and then was next to the red baron (the move was a back flip turn), the red baron was surprised.
- The allied man then picked up a hand gun, pointed it at the red baron and fired three times.
- One shot went straight through his throat, the second hit his eye, the third punched a hole in his head.
- The red baron slumped to the side.
- The slump forced the plane's joystick towards the dead baron and the plane flew up, then it sort of flipped in mid air and then sped towards the ground.
- The impact on the green field was an explosion.
- After this, the other allied planes had fought off and defeated the baron's colleages and the three allied planes flew side by side over victoriously earned territory.
- They shared their truimpth together while mid air.
- I am fairly sure this is where the film ended.

**Thanks for helping guys, this is all I remember, I would very much like to watch the film again**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the movie you're remembering is [Flyboys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyboys_(film)) - but with some details a bit askew.

The characters are Americans who join the French Air Force in 1916 (prior to the USA joining the war), and the major antagonist is the Black Falcon (likely modelled on the Red Baron, although with some more nefarious traits).

But a lot of the other details seem to match up - the attack on the zeppelin/blimp, the final fight with the antagonist being concluded with a pistol shot.

Also, the training scene matches your description (thanks @Walt)

Comment: And the training scene with the spinning chair is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIbGwU7vD-4).

Comment: Thanks for that, my memory of it was a bit fuzzy, but this is it. Thanks :)