# Why didn't the red baron shoot the allied plane?

Tags: plot-explanation, flyboys

It descendent from my previous *identify-this-movie* [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79672/movie-about-world-war-i) on *Flyboys* (2006):

When the allied guy lost his bullets, (the other guys were shaken off to fight off other planes) because they fell out of the gun, the red baron took aim directly behind him, the allied guy knew he was going to die and closed his eyes, put his head back and braced himself.

The red baron then fired but didn't hit the allied man. The red baron had all the time in the world.

**Why didn't the red baron shoot the allied pilot?**